# Bind two pandas dataframes containing lists

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes with same column and index names, containing list in each cell, looking like this:

```
df1
   A      B
c [1,2] [2,5]

d [3,5] [4,1]

df2
   A      B
c [2,3] [4,5]

d [2,3] [5,3]
```

i would like to have only one dataframe, looking like this:

```
df_1&2
      A         B
c [1,2,2,3] [2,5,4,5]

d [3,5,2,3] [4,1,5,3]
```

Any suggestions?

Another thing; how to join dataframes only where indexes are duplicated and skip the unique ones:

```
  df1
       A      B
    c [1,2] [2,5]

    e [3,5] [4,1]

    df2
       A      B
    c [2,3] [4,5]

    f [2,3] [5,3]
```

Where result would be:

```
   df1&2

          A         B
    c [1,2,2,3] [2,5,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join DataFrames by `+`, only necessary same index values and only columns filled by lists in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df1 + df2
print (df)
              A             B
c  [1, 2, 2, 3]  [2, 5, 4, 5]
d  [3, 5, 2, 3]  [4, 1, 5, 3]
```

EDIT:

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
df = df1.loc[idx] + df2.loc[idx]
```

Comment: Some of the indexes (and corresponidng lists) are present only in df1 and some of them only in df2. Is it possible to give a condition, to join only those lists based od indexes that exist in both dataframes and skip the unique ones?

Comment: @Kuki - Can you change data for thes, please?